# Why is app.locals.user constantly "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, hexo

I have user data in JS passed to me from Netifly, and I'd like to use it to detect whether the user is logged in or not.

In `user.js`:

```
const user = netlifyIdentity.currentUser();
```

But I can't figure out how to pass that data to 'app.locals.user' in EJS.

Once I do I can use load a different screen depending on wether the user is logged in or out.

In `_partial/header-post.ejs`:

```
<% if (locals.user) { %>
   here, user is defined
<% } %>
```

locals.user constantly comes up as "undefined" no matter what I try.

How can I pass my JS user data to my EJS local.user?

**UPDATE:res is not defined**

user.js

```
res.locals.user = netlifyIdentity.currentUser();
```

header-post.ejs

```
 <% if (res.locals.user == null){ %>
   <%= res.locals.user %>
 <% } %>
```

Still no go. Now, "res is not defined".

Comment: *But I can't figure out how to pass that data to 'app.locals.user' in EJS* - By assigning a value to 'app.locals.user ? FWIW, assigning it to app.locals is fundamentally wrong because there can be multiple users. If there's a place where it should be assigned, it's res.locals.user.

Comment: That makes sense, but then the question becomes how to assign it to res.locals.user?

Comment: By assigning it as `res.locals.user = ...`. The question doesn't mention that you use Express, while this is likely the case.

Comment: But when I assign res.locals.user = netlifyIdentity.currentUser(); it still comes up as undefined.

Comment: This totally depends on how you use EJS with Express. The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which is a requirement. It's possible that you will need to pass `res.locals` or `res.locals.user` to EJS on render.